# laravel migrate:fresh from ssh cpanel

Tags: laravel, ssh, cpanel, migrate

I have uploaded a project on my cpanel  after that I had gone to migrate from ssh

But after type php artisan migrate:fresh or php artisan migrate I gave this message from ssh

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `translations` add unique `translations_table_name_column_name_foreign_key_locale_unique`(`table_name`, `column_name`, `foreign_key`, `locale`))

What is the problem?

I have searched a link and the guide with the schema:: deffaultstring(191)

but does not work

It's so easy to import the database again but i dont want that

I want migrate from my ssh

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what the error says: `Specified key was too long`

You need to rename rename your tables / columns to be more short.